# Synchronize an image with the rest of the svg with D3js

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am trying to plot some points on a map. My map is a svg generated separately (in the PATH_PARAM file). It is supposed to act as a background, with details that must be at specific coordinates in the final plot. Even if it's not exactly that you can imagine the map is a picture of a face I traced myself (so I know its size and where are each elements in the map's referential) and I want to add points precisely in the middle of the eyes after importing it on my svg with D3.js.

For now I simply append it to the svg, like so: (this javascript is called during the loading of the page)

```
var SIZE_PARAM = 200;
var DATA_PARAM = [{position: [0,1]}, {position: [4,5]}] //actually it's a far more bigger set of points.
var graph = d3.select("#graph");
svg = graph.append("svg")
    .attr("width",window.innerWidth)
    .attr("height",window.innerHeight)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", 
        function () {svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")}
    ))
    .append("g");


background = svg.selectAll("image")
    .data([0])
    .enter()
    .append("svg:image");
background.attr("xlink:href", PATH_PARAM)
    .attr("width",SIZE_PARAM)
    .attr("height",SIZE_PARAM);


scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([dom_x_min, dom_x_max])
    .rangeRound([ 0, SIZE_PARAM ])
    .clamp(true);


circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(DATA_PARAM)
    .enter()
    .append("circle");
circles.attr("class", "point")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) {return scale(d.position[0]);})
    .attr("cy", function(d,i) {return scale(d.position[1]);})
    .attr("r", function(d,i) {return 1;})
```

The problem I got is that the map and the points are not synchronized with the map. The relative position between points is good, and I managed to have the same scale for the map and the points by setting a unique SIZE_PARAM parameter, but there is a translation between the points and the map. This translation is not visible for a small number of points (like the two of the example) but becomes more and more noticeable as this number increases.

Following some advice I added this to the CSS:

```
#graph * {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

But it doesn't solve my problem.

What can I do to synchronize the map with the points ?

Comment: Please create a SO snippet, or a fiddle, so we can see your problem in action.

Comment: My datas are something like ten thousands of coordinates in a json file automatically generated by another program and the problem can be observed only when there is that much data. That's why it seems difficult to me to show it in action.

Comment: This question is pretty much impossible to answer without seeing it (and even then it's going to be difficult).  `The problem I got is that the map and the points are not synchronized with the map`, well, what's this map you speak of?  How's it generated?  What does "synchronizing" to the points look like?  Too many unknowns here.

Comment: I added some explanations about what is supposed to be this map and what I mean by "synchronizing". The map is generated by a server through a Python script in a svg format and directly send to the client without saving it.